# div floats left right issue, not displaying in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-9

I've been having issues for a couple of days now with IE9 handling floating divs (left and right) for example on this [page](http://www.pemsea.org/publications/sustainable-development-strategy-seas-east-asia-sds-sea).

I have one div float left 
"<"div style="float:left; width:460px;" ">"
and another div float right
"<"div style="float:right; width:220px;" ">"

For some reason, IE9 is not displaying this portion where those divs are. IE10, FF and Chrome seems to handle this well. Too bad I can't do away with IE9, analytics shows at least 15% of users are on this version.

Appreciate any advice. Please excuse all the commented inline styling. css and codes, been testing exhaustively already.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close or Remove unclosed HTML comment from

```
<div id="main-content" class="region clear-block">
<style type="text/css">
<!-- Jerome, publication item view, left main content, right block
#pub-item-view-page-parent {
    padding: 0 auto;
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Sorry for the carelessness! Death by trailing --> :) Thanks Abhineet!